# Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use react-bootstrap-table2 in my project to create a simple bootstrap table, but am getting the error:

> Failed to Compile: Module not found: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/src/routes/home'.

I did install all the necessary packages and verified that bootstrap.min.css exists where it should.

My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'TV',
        'price': 1000
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Mobile',
        'price': 500
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Book',
        'price': 20
      },
    ],
    columns: [{
      dataField: 'id',
      text: 'Product ID'
    },
    {
      dataField: 'name',
      text: 'Product Name'
    }, {
      dataField: 'price',
      text: 'Product Price',
      sort: true
    }]
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
        <BootstrapTable 
        striped
        hover
        keyField='id' 
        data={ this.state.products } 
        columns={ this.state.columns } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "codist.org",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.25",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^1.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Any suggestions for how to resolve that error?

Comment: Directories in `node_modules` does not need the path prefix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

When not specifying a path, Node/webpack will search for the import inside `node_modules` folder. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but this is the correct way to import modules from the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Will accept as soon as Stack allows me to.

Comment: Whwew shoud this line go?

Comment: This solution also worked for me when trying to import font-awesome       @import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code use "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" in styles for angular.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).