# bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css can't be found

Tags: react-native, react-bootstrap

I tried to install react-bootstrap and followed these instructions:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

However after starting the app (simulated device via Android Studio) I receive this error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` from `index.js`: bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css could not be found within the project.
```

My dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-native": "0.61.5"
```

And both modules are within `node_modules` and so is the file `bootstrap.min.css`.
I tried things like

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; (should be wrong anyways);
```

(in index.js and also App.js like mentioned in the instructions)

I also read here:

https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1325

and here:

[Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081212/cant-resolve-node-modules-bootstrap-dist-css-bootstrap-min-css)

but I have the import like in the given answer.

I tried an older version of react-bootstrap and bootstrap and I deleted all node_modules and resinstalled them even though the "missing" file is there.

My project is basically a vanilla react-native project. 
I just started with `npx react-native init name` and tried to add bootstrap, so nothing has changed.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to use react bootstrap with react-native project.

```
 react-bootstrap : only support react.js projects not in react-native
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: Uhm I don't know how I missed that....thank you even though it was not the answer I was looking for